# Explain Godel's Second Incompleteness Theorem: Why is A Theory Unable to Prove its Consistency if it is Consistent?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation, metalogic

From Peter Smith's Godel book (p. 6)

"ConT" means "theory T is consistent"

"GT" is "Godel unprovable sentence"

ConT $\to$ GT inside T

...it immediately follows that if T is consistent it cannot prove ContT.

Can someone please explain?  Many thanks.

Comment: We know that if $T$ is consistent, then $T$ cannot prove $GT$. We also know that $T$ can prove $Con(T)\to GT$. If $T$ can also prove $Con(T)$, then since it can prove both $Con(T)$ and $Con(T)\to GT$, then it can prove $GT$ (by Modus ponens). Since $T$ can prove $GT$ if and only if $T$ is inconsistent, then $T$ can prove $Con(T)$ if and only if $T$ is inconsistent. In particular, if $T$ is consistent, then it cannot prove $Con(T)$.

Comment: Many thanks for your help  Prof. Magidin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $T$ be a consistent theory. Then, by definition of consistency, for every sentence $\rho$ in $T$, it's *not* the case that both $\rho$ and $\neg \rho$ are provable in $T$.

As you stated, if $T$ is consistent, then $T$ contains at least one Godel sentence. Thus, there is at least one Godel sentence in $T$. By definition, a Godel sentence $\phi$ of $T$ is a well-formed formula with the following characteristics:

$1$. $\phi$ is constructed in such a way that it effectively means "*This sentence is not provable in $T$.*"

$2$. $\phi$ is in fact true.

Hereafter, lets assume $T$ can prove its own consistency. This implies that for every sentence $\rho$ in $T$, $T$ can actually *prove* it's not the case that both $\rho$ and $\neg \rho$ are provable in $T$. In other words, for every sentence $\rho$, $T$ can prove that $\rho$ is not provable or that $\neg \rho$ is not provable in $T$. Well, if $T$ can prove this about every sentence in $T$, then it can certainly prove this about a Godel sentence $\phi$ in $T$. Here is where things get interesting...

Suppose $T$ can prove $\phi$ is not provable in $T$. This immediately leads to a contradiction because, as a result of $1$ and $2$ above, it cannot be proven in $T$ that $\phi$ is not provable in $T$. Now suppose $T$ can prove $\neg \phi$ is not provable in $T$. Again, we arrive at a contradiction because $\neg \phi$ effectively means "*This sentence is provable in $T$*," implying $T$ will have proven that a provable statement is not provable.

Since each case above results in a contradiction under the assumption that $T$ can prove its own consistency, this assumption must be false. In other words, it must be the case $T$ cannot prove its own consistency.

Therefore, if $T$ is a consistent theory, then $T$ cannot prove its own consistency.

Comment: . I'm new to math and logic.

Comment: Thanks for your response

Comment: No problem! If you're satisfied with the answer, then please click the green check mark to close the post. Thanks!